# PostgreSQL query issue 2

Tags: sql, postgresql

The relations are:

```
Event (etype, description)                     primary key - etype

City (cname, country, population)              primary key - cname

Disaster (cname, dyear, etype, casualties)     primary key - cname, dyear
```

I need to write a query which tells which country faced all types (etype in relation) of disasters.

How do i do that?

I have this so far:

```
select country
from city natural join disaster, (select count(etype) as a
                                  from event) as A
group by country, etype
having count(country) = max(A.a)
```

Comment: So whats wrong with your query?

Comment: It gives back all countries that faced any disaster that > disaster types in event relation

Comment: For your tables, you need to add country into disaster table against the common named cities among the countries.

Comment: Consider this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tgfz1oA9KFPho8ezcQTEDL/0 interesting case for common named cities. Certianly there should be USA but at least one of the other countries shouldn't appear in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always count:

```
select c.country
from disasters d join
     cities c
     on d.cname = c.cname
group by c.country
having count(distinct d.etype) = (select count(*) from events);
```

Comment: I cant understand this goup by. You combined both tables together but you group only by table c?

Comment: Well, the country and event are not in the same table, so something has to be joined together.